# Javascript get element class or data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css

At the moment I have a javascript function which looks for an id and changes some CSS. However I want this function to run on multiple divs. Therefore I need my function to look for a class or a data attribute. Please can you help me!

```
<script>
  var div = document.getElementById('hover')
  div.onclick = function () {
    this.style.width = '800px'
    this.style.transition = 'all 1s'
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap all your elements inside a common parent, then you apply your `click` event handler to that parent, checking the `target` that originated the event.

Doing so you need to attach the event just to a single element (and not to every single element).

Also, your style should be declared in the CSS as a class, so you only need to switch that specific class (and it's always better to keep off css from javascript, for the mantainability)

here is a simple example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPwXVr

CSS

```
.open {
  width: 800px;
  -webkit-transition  : all 1s;
  -moz-transition  : all 1s;
  transition  : all 1s;
  background: red;
}
```

JS

```
 document.getElementById('wrap').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  var target = ev.target
  if (target.nodeName === 'DIV') {
      target.className = 'open';        
  } 
}, false);
```

---

if the structure of your markup makes impossibile to use a common wrapper you could attach the event on the `body` element, like so

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOwPWY?editors=011

CSS

```
.element {
  width: 800px; 
  -webkit-transition  : all 1s;
  -moz-transition  : all 1s;
  transition  : all 1s;
}

.element.open {
  background: red;
}
```

JS

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   var t = ev.target;

   /* I used classList for the sake of brevity, check caniuse.com
      for its support across browser */

   if (t.classList.contains('element')) {
       t.classList.toggle('open');        
   } 
}, false);
```

Comment: That cool, but I need it to be lots of them around the page so it can be wrapped in an ID

Comment: you could attach the event also on body - I'll prepare another example

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I'm really confused on how to implement it into my project, here is my current code (https://jsfiddle.net/txoyuvqn/1/) please can you help me,

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `class`, which is better. And loop it through!

```
<script>
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('hover');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    divs[i].onclick = function () {
      this.style.width = '800px'
      this.style.transition = 'all 1s'
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }
</script>
```

Example using `addEventListener`:

```
<script>
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('hover');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    divs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      this.style.width = '800px'
      this.style.transition = 'all 1s'
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener` when looping

Comment: @vihan1086 Lemme include. `:D`

Comment: it's better if you use event delegation

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan how come?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Also is there a way to effect another classes CSS when clicking?

Comment: @PraveenKumar its not working, here is my code please can you try and help me fix it? https://jsfiddle.net/txoyuvqn/